# Create 3-dimensional slice (or more than 3)

Tags: arrays, go, slice

How do you create a 3 (or more) dimensional slice in Go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var xs, ys, zs = 5, 6, 7 // axis sizes
var world = make([][][]int, xs) // x axis
func main() {
    for x := 0; x < xs; x++ {
        world[x] = make([][]int, ys) // y axis
        for y := 0; y < ys; y++ {
            world[x][y] = make([]int, zs) // z axis
            for z := 0; z < zs; z++ {
                world[x][y][z] = (x+1)*100 + (y+1)*10 + (z+1)*1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That shows the pattern which makes it easier to make n-dimensional slices.

Comment: Wish we could just say `world:=make([11,100][11,100][11,100]int)` where 11=len, 100=cap and refer to this directly with `world[x][y][z]` ...

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you need a multi dimensional *slice*? If the dimensions of the n-dimensional space are known/derivable at compile time then using an array is easier and better run time access performing. Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        var world [2][3][5]int
        for i := 0; i < 2*3*5; i++ {
                x, y, z := i%2, i/2%3, i/6
                world[x][y][z] = 100*x + 10*y + z
        }
        fmt.Println(world)
}
```

(Also [here](http://play.golang.org/p/ZOzLYEYDSm))

---

Output

```
[[[0 1 2 3 4] [10 11 12 13 14] [20 21 22 23 24]] [[100 101 102 103 104] [110 111 112 113 114] [120 121 122 123 124]]]
```

Comment: That's an interesting way of handling the loops. What's the math based on? I can't quite work it out.

Comment: My quick hunch would have been for i%2,i%3,i%5.

Comment: "Unsimplified" it goes like: x = (i/(1))%2, y = (i/(1.2))%3, z = (i/(1.2.3))%5. HTH ;-)